# Wrong sql query generated by hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I have order and item entity classes in my program. In order class there is a Set of 
Item. When I insert an order the order details must be inserted to Order table. And items in the Set must be inserted to Items table which has a foreign key to order_id in Order table. Therefore the query that i want is :

```sql
insert into ordertb (cName) values (?);
insert into item (id, order_id, qty) values(?,?,?);
insert into item (id, order_id, qty) values(?,?,?);
insert into item (id, order_id, qty) values(?,?,?);
// until all the items are inserted
```

But hibernate generates the following query :

```sql
Hibernate: insert into ordertb (cName) values (?)
Hibernate: update item set qty=?, order_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update item set qty=?, order_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update item set qty=?, order_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update item set order_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update item set order_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update item set order_id=? where id=?
```

Here is my Mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Order" table="ordertb">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the Order detail. 
    </meta>
    <id name="order" type="int" column="order_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="cName" column="cName" type="string"/>
    <set name="items" table="item" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key>
            <column name="order_id" not-null="true"></column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Item"/>
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TestComp.java where i call the method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Deepan
 */
public class TestComp {

    private static SessionFactory factory; 

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         System.out.println("Error");
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 

      }
      TestComp ME = new TestComp();

      Order od=new Order();
        Set<Item> items=new HashSet<Item>();

      Item i1=new Item(1, 5, od);
      items.add(i1);
      Item i2=new Item(2, 20, od);
      items.add(i2);
      Item i3=new Item(3, 15, od);
      items.add(i3);

      od.setOrder(200);
      od.setcName("Deepan");
      od.setItems(items);
      /* Add few employee records in database */


      Integer car1 = ME.addOrder(od);
        System.out.println(od.getOrder()+" : "+od.getcName()+" : "+od.getItems());
      //Integer car2 = ME.addOrder(6, "Benz", "gtr");
      //Integer car3 = ME.addOrder(7, "Audi", "sdf");
    }

     public Integer addOrder(Order order) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer carVIN = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            carVIN = (Integer) session.save(order);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return carVIN;
    }


}
```

What is wrong? If you need any additional information just mention in the comment. As I am quite new to hibernate please give me a detailed answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add please code snippet where you're persisting your object

Comment: I have added the code to the question

Comment: Items contain Item objects that contain Order Objects that contain Items? something is wrong with your data graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get i1, i2, i3 as parameters into the method. Then add the following code after carVIN = (Integer) session.save(order);

```
session.save(i1);
session.save(i2);
session.save(i3);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks that worked and update queries are changed as insert queries.